# Setting up Google adwords test account

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I am developing an ads manager application in PHP using Google adwords.

I have downloaded and tried to set up this code : https://github.com/medio/Google-Adwords-API-PHP but its not working.

I know that sandbox account is deprecated and that i should use a test account.(https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/test-accounts).

This is the what I found on the documentation:

> "To obtain a Test Account you need to first create an MCC test account. All client accounts created under this test MCC account will be automatically marked as Test Accounts.All calls made with the AdWords API require a developer token, but the token doesn't have to be approved for calls made to Test Accounts; you can make requests against a Test Account while the token application is still pending. The token can be obtained from the AdWords API Center page under the My Account tab in your MCC production account (not MCC test account) AdWords user interface."

So my questions are this :

1. What is the difference between MCC production and MCC test account and how do I create each of these accounts?
2. How do I create a client account under the MCC test account? (should I link it in anyway)
3. are the video tutorials on this page outdated?(https://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-php/).
4. Do I need a developer token for testing?

Comment: one more question about test account. Test account is asking to enter billing information. I read somewhere google is not charging for usage of test account, they will just keep billing information with them. is it true?

Answer (score 0):

1.On MCC test account ads are not served, this account is only for testing and all changes on data will not have affect on anything.
For creating normal MCC account type in google "create mcc account" and you will se link.
For creating test MCC account click on link in https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/test-accounts or type in google "create test mcc account".

2.On test MCC dashboard you will se button "CREATE ACCOUNT".

3.Yes. All tutorials and resources about adwords and analytics api is in my opinion confusing and poor quality so you will need spend much time for this.

4.Yes. Developer token is only in production MCC account but it can be used for testing accounts.

Comment: one more question about test account. Test account is asking to enter billing information. I read somewhere google is not charging for usage of test account, they will just keep billing information with them. is it true?

Comment: No "CREATE ACCOUNT" button on starting page. What to do?

Comment: running to the same issue, creating a test account does not seem possible.  The documentation is incorrect or outdated